# Mobile website does not scroll when zoomed in

Tags: html, css, mobile, web

I am currently coding a website by scratch. I am using a free hosting site, and embedding my website into blogger. I have the following code (located in my index.html) on my current website in order to show something different (content that is being shown on mobile devices are located in iphone.html) when on a mobile device, specifically, iPhone's:

```
<script language=javascript>
<!--
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ||     (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
   location.replace("/hi.html");
}
-->
</script>
```

**Now, when viewing the mobile website (at http://solsticedesigns.comli.com/), and I want to zoom in, I no longer have the ability to scroll left/right, or up/down.**

I would appreciate any bit of assistance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Blogger is the issue here - but has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The zooming and then scrolling up / down, left / right works fine for me:

Tried it on my **iPhone6s** in **landscape and normal view + on safari and chrome**.

Make sure it is not a problem with your personal device!

Good Luck!